# How to remove "leave blank for all" message from Views exposed filter

Tags: views

After updating the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module from 3.11 to 3.13, I get an annoying text that says:

> Leave blank for all. Otherwise, the first selected **term** will be the default instead of "Any".

[image]

Does anyone know how to remove it, besides using CSS?

This only happens in *taxonomy term* exposed filters.

Could it be a bug?

Comment: sometime it happens when you check the select all checkbox in the options checkboxes. leaving those checkboxes empty solve problem in most cases

Comment: Looking like a bug, it says the exact same thing in the configuration settings, which is probably meant to be there only.

Comment: Yes, it's a bug, you can track it here: http://drupal.org/node/2611958.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a problem with view 3.13. It happened due to this commit https://www.drupal.org/node/339384#comment-10548388.

Stated as:

> Issue #339384 by colan: Added help text to keep the exposed filter
>   terms list unset to keep unfiltered "Any" option default.

Apply this [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/views-339384-15.patch) or revert your view back to version 3.11.

Comment: patch is the way to go as there was a security update. thx

Comment: Yeah!! you are right.

Comment: There's an updated patch here: https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/views-fix-exposed-filter-description-339384-36-7.x-3.x.patch

Comment: @NikhilBanait no problem. This post really helped me so I wanted to share the update with others.

Comment: @DooKie my pleasure!!

Comment: I've applied the patch - how do I remove the text?

Comment: You can track this issue here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2611958.

Comment: Views 3.14 solved this issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

A quick, temporary "fix" is to use String Override module to hide this string. Just leave Replacement field blank or change to more applicable string.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by "hiding" the helptext message from being displayed using CSS. 
.description {
    display: none;}
I am not sure though if this poses any security risk. I think this is better than hacking Views or at least until patch is included to the current version (not the dev version).